# Error: Compile Error: Unexpected token 'taskIds'. at line 8 column 9

Tags: trigger

I am a novice when it comes to creating triggers.  I am trying to add the first outbound call from a task to the Lead object and I found this trigger, but I keep getting the error:

> Error: Compile Error: Unexpected token 'taskIds'. at line 8 column 9

Any help would be appreciated.

```java
trigger TaskTrigger on Task (before insert) {
    
    /*   Trigger to populate a field labelled Call_made__c on the Lead object 
    with the Date/Time of the First call made   */
    
    System.debug('Trigger TaskTrigger Start ----------------------------------------------------');
                
    Set taskIds = new Set();
    //Set of TaskIDs - used for SOQL
        
    /* Only pull in Type Call to this Trigger
  Other Tasks should not change First Call Date field */
    
    for(Task ptl : Trigger.new) {
       //Populate list of IDs to work with - Outbound calls get added
           if (ptl.WhoId != null && (ptl.CallType == 'Outbound')) {
              taskIds.add(ptl.WhoId);
            }
        }
    
  if (taskIds.size() > 0) {
    //Only do something if we have TaskIDs to work with
    //Get all the Leads we'll update:
    
    List leadList = [SELECT Id, Call_made__c FROM lead where Id IN :taskIds];    
    
    //Build map of Leads
            
            for (Lead l : leadList) {
          if (l.Call_made__c == Null) {
                        //If there is no First Call Made populate it
                         l.Call_made__c = System.today();
                        System.debug('Update First Call Made');
                    }
                    else if (l.Call_made__c > System.Today()) {
                      l.Call_made__c = System.today();

                        //Check if there is an earlier date in there
                        System.debug('Older date already set for First Call Made - leaving value');                        
                    }
              
            }
    
    //Set new Call_made__c date
    update leadList;
        
  } //end if statement

    System.debug('Trigger TaskTrigger End ----------------------------------------------------');

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a type when you declare a collection (a list, set, or map)

Wrong:

```
Set taskIds = new Set();
```

Correct:

```
// The "type" that the collection holds is specified in between angle braces
Set<Id> taskIds = new Set<Id>();
```

Note that you also have the same issue with your list of leads, and you'll need to specify the appropriate type (`Lead` this time instead of `Id`) for that one as well.

Comment: The [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_sets.htm) have a good snippet here. *To declare a set, use the `Set` keyword followed by the primitive data type name within `<>` characters. For example...*